# JavaScript - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is wrong with this sample code? o_O

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log("Testing");
                $('#test').append("Test");​
            });
        </script>
        <title>Sin título 4</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="test">Hello world.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It says that error happens in line 9: `$('#test').append("Test");​`

Comment: That code works http://jsfiddle.net/2hDbL/

Comment: Apparently not in my IDE editor... phpDesigner on my localhost.. WAMP.

Comment: I wouldn't trust any IDE for debugging JavaScript. Trust the browsers.

Comment: Yes... my Chrome browser is giving the error.

Comment: Do you get that error with my jsfiddle too? Anyway, you could try this, as per jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/#example-1): `$('#test').append(document.createTextNode("Test"));`.

Comment: Works fine for me on the jsfiddle in chrome.

Try pasting `$('#test').append("Test");` directly into the chrome console and see what it says.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have an illegal invisible character at the end of this line...

```
$('#test').append("Test");​// <-- right before this comment
```

Delete the line entirely, and retype it, or make sure the cursor is after all characters on the line, and hit backspace until you see characters actually being removed.

This happens sometimes if you copy & paste code from jsFiddle.

The charCode of the offending character is 8203.

Comment: How would one go about finding these illegal text characters themselves?

Comment: @Prusprus: Here's a [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554416/how-to-reliably-strip-invisible-characters-that-break-code) that may help. I don't have much better than that to offer. Good luck!