# How to reliably strip invisible characters that break code?

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to build a bookmarklet and got slammed with this issue which I was just able to figure out: a `\u8203` character, which Chrome unhelpfully tells me in my block of code (upon pasting into the JS console) is an `"Invalid character ILLEGAL".

Luckily Safari was the one that told me it was a `\u8203`.

I am editing the code in the Sublime Text 2 editor and somehow copying in and out of it (I also tried TextEdit) fails to remove it.

Is there some sort of website somewhere that will strip all characters other than ASCII?

When I try to save as ISO 8859 but it will save it back as UTF-8 "because of unsupported characters".

... Yeah. that's the point. Get rid of my unsupported evil characters.

What am I supposed to do? Edit my file in a hex editor?

FYI I actually solved it by re-typing the code (which originated from this site by the way).

Comment: I just did some Googling and found [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=619792) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/php-how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: How about something that processes my clipboard. Or a website with a set of text inputs that I can copy/paste with.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with Javascript only (I'm assuming this is what you're using, because of the tag in your question). You can, however, write a small Javascript script with a little help of Flash (I believe there are ready tools for that) that will read the clipboard then do the RegEx replacement then write to the clipboard again.

Comment: I'm sure it's easy to make a loop in js that filters chars in 1-127 ASCII range.

Comment: Wait wait, are we talking about characters in a string? or characters in your code itself, like `if[*] (true){}` where `*` is the invisible char?

Comment: Characters in general. The code I write tends to not require anything outside of ASCII. In fact the only characters I want to keep are the ones accessible on a QWERTY keyboard. Why would I write in a language that I can't type easily? Consider what happened to me: some invisible character (the `\u8203`) got stuck into my file and it follows the code into the clipboard. Including the js file normally is fine but when I paste the same exact code I just copied into the console I get "ILLEGAL CHARACTER OMGWTF" from the browser without a line number.

Comment: > Is there some sort of website somewhere that will strip all characters
> other than ASCII? You could use [this website](http://jsfiddle.net/n9PNs/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the easiest way I can think of is to use `sed`

```
sed -i 's/[^[:print:]]//g' your_script.js
//            ^^^^^ this can also be 'ascii'
```

or using `tr`

```
tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < old_script.js > new_script.js
```

Comment: will that even match the character (which isnt in the 128-255 ascii range)?

Comment: @StevenLu, alright, think of it as white-listing. You wanna keep ONLY ASCII characters, so you don't really care about `\u8203`. I'll explain further in the answer.

Comment: @StevenLu, apparently I made a mistake. I matched the opposite of what you want. Note: you can do the same with `RegEx` of any language, do you have `php` or `perl` installation?

Comment: So I agree that `sed` or `tr` is a solid solution but what about when I am on windows?

Comment: @dda well, yeah. That's what Adnan's original example did

Comment: I repeat. ASCII is 0 to 127. ASCII doesn't have codepoints above that. So the expression you used, `in the 128-255 ascii range` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @dda You are correct. I conflated ASCII with the vague notion of "8 bit characters".

Comment: I switched my accept to this answer because depending on a webpage and various copy-paste clipboard shenanigans is slightly asinine. It's really better to keep things simple, and the best way to keep it simple is to have a small command line utility that can be used to scan a source code file for rogue characters. Then one can and *should* use a hex editor to do the dirty business.

Answer (score 14):

> Is there some sort of website somewhere that will strip all characters
>   other than ASCII?

You could use [this website](http://jsfiddle.net/n9PNs/)

You can recreate the website using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>- jsFiddle demo</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            textarea {
                width: 800px;
                height: 480px;
                outline: none;
                font-family: Monaco, Consolas, monospace;
                border: 0;
                padding: 15px;
                color: hsl(0, 0%, 27%);
                background-color: #F6F6F6;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[ 
            $(function () {
                $("button").click(function () {
                    $("textarea").val(
                             $("textarea").val().replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, "")
                    );
                    $("textarea").focus()[0].select();
                });
            }); //]]>
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <textarea></textarea>
        <button>Remove</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Short and sweet. Maybe I'll implement this on my website. I'll add in some goodies like a report of which characters were dropped, and where they were.

Comment: moral of the story is don't copy from the Javascript buffer in jsfiddle. They use invisible characters to do strange things in there.

Comment: This is an answer, and it answers the question. but it is just a link that can become dead. Add your code to the answer so it can be useful for when that ever happens....

Comment: Thank you very much for this. In our website, our JS codes have the "Â" character on every JS line. Filtering the code through what you provided worked by removing that character, however. Using it as is, killed the format of the code, so adding a single space keeps the format and removes the bad characters. This is my edited version of your project, with a single space. http://jsfiddle.net/carrzkiss/8pwkLxqa/1/

Answer (score 6):

you can use regex to filter everything out of 0-127. For example in javascript:

```
text.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "")
```

x00 = 0, x7f = 127

Comment: This keeps only ascii character set, so removes all non-western unicode characters. We only want to remove control characters, not foreign letters.

Answer (score 0):

Nontechnical solution: paste your text into a new email message in Gmail and click Tx (clear formatting, in the formatting menu). Worked for me.

Comment: You can do the same with something like Notepad.exe. I tend to do this but with Vim (I might paste into Sublime Text, then save as file, then open from Vim)